# What does the following (simple) .htaccess rule do?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm learning a lot about .htaccess, I found the following line in a project, but i really can't make out what it does

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
```

I know that **^** indicated the beginning of the url to match and
that **$** indicated the end of the string. But there's nothing in between so maybe this one is redundant?

Answer (score 1):

This one is not redundant rule it is matching `^$` (empty pattern which means home/landing URI `/`) and forwarding it to `index.php` thus when you open `http://domain.com` it is showing `http://domain.com/index.php`

Though same thing can be achieved using:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Would it also be the same as this? RewriteRule .* index.php [L], Because that line is above the one i posted.. thanks!

Comment: No they are different. `DirectoryIndex` sets only default page when you open `example.com/`